# Power analysis: How are sample sizes calculated when the distribution is asymmetric?

Tags: statistical-power

I want to calculate the sample size required to detect a 50% change in the probability of an binary outcome.

The base probability is .2. A 50% increase would go from .2 to .3. A 50% decrease would go from .2 to .1.

In this example, assuming a normal distribution, it should be easier to detect an increase compared to a decrease because there will be more observations in the former. Using power.prop.test in R confirms that the former requires a smaller sample size. However, using pwr command gives only a single sample size. How is that single sample size derived?

Answer (score 1):

You were probably doing something wrong with the `pwr` package, as it gives two different sample sizes in your two different scenarios, for a test of proportions with two independent samples:

```
library(pwr)
pwr.2p.test(h = ES.h(p1=0.2,p2=0.3), sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, alternative = "two.sided")$n
291.6887
pwr.2p.test(h = ES.h(p1=0.2,p2=0.1), sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, alternative = "two.sided")$n
194.9081
```

You might have noticed that this is slightly different from the two sample sizes given by `stats::power.prop.test` ($\approx 294$ and $\approx 199$), as the two functions rely on different calculations. This difference is addressed in [Why do these power functions for difference in proportions give different answers?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83700/why-do-these-power-functions-for-difference-in-proportions-give-different-answer) . Note that the two functions disagree more as the two proportions get smaller. If it's a problem (e.g. if collecting observations is costly or if you need to reach very precise power), using simulations may be useful for estimating the right sample size to choose.

Also, you might want to check if this really a test of proportions for two independent populations you need. If it's not, you should look at other R packages or functions for related power calculations.